# Preventing redefinition issue in case of separating the declaration and definition of template class

Tags: c++, templates, one-definition-rule

The question is that in case of stencil out a class via templates, then include it to use as usual: It'll be gotten the error explained in below:

If it is demanded to use struct Something straightforwardly within Node.inl. It needs to include "Node.h" header as follows, but this will comes with some troubles. We violate the rule of one definition, but the template class needs to include their definitions in the same file as they are declared. Otherwise, the compiler will forget to stencil out the member functions upon the instance created. As a result, we can not use these functions via the instance initialized. So how do we manage that while we want to preserve the separateness of declarations and definitions, persist not violate one definition rule?

Node.inl:

```
#include "Node.h"

void foo(){
    struct Something s{1, 2};
}

template <class T>
Node<T>::Node(int data, Node<T> *next) : m_data{data}, m_next{next} {}

template <class T>
void Node<T>::setData(int data) {
    m_data = data;
}

template <class T>
int Node<T>::getData() const {
    return m_data;
}

template <class T>
void Node<T>::setNext(Node<T> *next) {
    m_next = next;
}

template <class T>
Node<T> * Node<T>::getNext() const {
    return m_next;
}

template <class T>
void Node<T>::allocMemoryNext() {
    m_next = new Node<T>();
}
```

Node.h:

```
#ifndef THE1_NODE_H
#define THE1_NODE_H

struct Something{
    int x;
    int y;
};

template <class T>
class Node {
private:
    T m_data;
    Node *m_next;

public:
    explicit Node(int data = 0, Node *next = nullptr);

    void setData(int data);

    [[nodiscard]] int getData() const;

    void setNext(Node *next);

    [[nodiscard]] Node *getNext() const;

    void allocMemoryNext();
};

#include "Node.inl"

#endif //THE1_NODE_H
```

Answer (score 1):

> we want to preserve the separateness of declarations and definitions

There is no such "separateness" as far as templates are concerned. In order for anyone to use them, they must be defined. And Node.h provides those definitions.

Node.inl is *part of* Node.h. You have logically separated the text into different files, but they aren't separate as far as any practical reality is concerned. Every user of Node.h should be getting Node.inl's stuff too, which is why you `#include "Node.inl"` at the end of the file. Nobody but Node.h should be including Node.inl, so there is no reason for Node.inl to `#include "Node.h"`.

So there is no problem, once you remove the needless include of a thing that is definitely already there.

Comment: But I may want to use a structure which is defined in "Node.h" in "Node.inl" so I need to include. Actually, this is what is being asked.

Comment: @ibrahimkoz: No, you don't need to include any such thing. Files in C++ are not separate, locked off construct. `#include`sion is just a copy/paste of text from one file into another. Node.inl is included after a bunch of definitions in Node.h, so it has access to them.

Comment: Nope, you're wrong classes and structs need to be included to use in-place.

Comment: @ibrahimkoz: They don't need to be "included"; they need to be *visible*. And they are visible. Remove the `#include "Node.h"` from your `Node.inl` file, and you will find that it can see `Something` just fine. Provided that `Node.h` is the only file that includes `Node.inl`.

Comment: Nope, you can not access members of Something in that case. So you can not do anything while you can see it.

Comment: @ibrahimkoz: Are you doing everything I said? Specifically, not including `Node.inl` anywhere but `Node.h` (which BTW, also includes not *compiling* it as if it were a .cpp file. Treat it as if it were a header file, because *it is a header file*). Because it works for me just fine.